# establishing a bijection between $\{0, 1\}^n$ and $2^A$ for suitable n ∈ N

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I have been doing practice problems relating to set theory and one of my questions was the following:

> Prove, by induction, that $|2^A|$ = $2^{|A|}$ for every finite set A.

I have solved this, however, the follow-up problem is the same statement, although now with a bijection as proof:

> Prove the same statement by establishing a bijection between $\{0, 1\} ^n$ and $2^A$ for suitable *n*∈ℕ

I am struggling to figure out what this question is asking me exactly, let alone efficiently carrying out the bijective proof that is desired. Could someone explain/run me through how I would be able to prove this through bijection as is described in the problem?

Answer (score 3):

- What is the cardinality of $\{0,1\}^n$ (in terms of $n$)?
- Given that the cardinality of $2^A$ is $2^{|A|}$, does this suggest some necessary condition on $A$ in order for $|\{0,1\}^n| = |2^A|$ to hold?
- Try to let $0$ and $1$ encode membership in subsets of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea to show is to use a binary base like below
$$(0000000...000)_2=0\\(0000000...001)_2=1\\(0000000...010)_2=2\\
(0000000...011)_2=3\\(0000000...100)_2=4\\\vdots\\(0111111...111)_2=2^n-1\\(1000000...000)_2=2^n$$ and

there is $2^n$ element to make a bijection